# Как добавить дополнительную колонку в список методов доставки в панели управления WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть вот такой код,

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'woocommerce_shipping_instances_form_fields_filters');
function woocommerce_shipping_instances_form_fields_filters(){
    foreach( WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_instance_form_fields_' . $shipping_method->id, 'shipping_methods_additional_custom_field');
    }
}

function shipping_methods_additional_custom_field( $settings ) {
    $settings['shipping_comment'] = array(
        'title'         => __('Shipping Comment', 'woocommerce'),
        'type'          => 'textarea', 
        'placeholder'   => __( 'Enter any additional comments for this shipping method.', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $settings;
}
```

который добавляет дополнительное поле для комментария, при редактировании метода доставки в настройках Woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне добавить дополнительную колонку в списке методов доставки в настройках Woocommerce и что бы в ней отображались эти комментарии?

Вот здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://woo.com/document/shipping-method-api/

Comment: @SeVlad Спасибо за ссылку, но я не знаю язык php