# Как массово обновить посты вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужно обновить большое кол-во опубликованных постов на WordPress.
Подскажите подойдет для этой задачи такой код:

```
// Запускаем функцию обновления постов один раз 
add_action( 'wp', 'update_old_posts_once' ); 
function update_old_posts_once() { 
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'update_old_posts_event' ) ) { 
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 900, 'update_old_posts_event' ); 
    } 
} 
 
// Функция обновления постов 
add_action( 'update_old_posts_event', 'update_old_posts' ); 
function update_old_posts() { 
    // Получаем список всех постов, которые были опубликованы более 30 дней назад 
    $old_posts = get_posts( array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'date_query' => array( 
            array( 
                'column' => 'post_date', 
                'before' => '30 days ago' 
            ) 
        ), 
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    ) ); 
     
    // Обновляем каждый пост с задержкой в 15 минут
    $delay = 900; // 15 минут в секундах
    foreach ( $old_posts as $post ) { 
        $post_id = $post->ID; 
         
        // Создаем массив с новыми значениями полей 
        $updated_post = array( 
            'ID' => $post_id, 
            // Здесь можно указать любые поля, которые нужно обновить 
            // Например: 
            //'post_title' => 'Новый заголовок', 
            //'post_content' => 'Новый текст', 
           //'post_excerpt' => 'Новый отрывок', 
            //'post_category' => array( 2, 4, 6 ) // Новые категории 
        ); 
         
        // Обновляем пост 
        wp_update_post( $updated_post ); 

        // Создаем задержку в 15 минут перед обновлением следующего поста
        sleep( $delay );
    }
```

Comment: Вы же ничерта не меняете в постах + все остальное едва ли будет хорошо работать, особенно с большим количеством постов. Есть вероятность, что еще на моменте с `get_posts()` все уже перестанет работать.

Comment: @Simon, А можете подсказать, как правильно сделать?

Comment: Плагин попробовать не желаете? [Bulk Post Update Date](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-post-update-date/), так как есть минимум несколько вариантов, в зависимости от Ваших обстоятельств и описание явно не влезет в комментарий.

Comment: @Simon, Спасибо за совет! 
Кстати протестировал код, на тестовом сайте. Изменял дату публикации поста.
`$updated_post = array( 
            'ID' => $post_id, 
            'post_date' => '2023-03-26',
        );`
Код работает! Дата публикации постов меняется!

Подскажите, а как сделать, что бы проставлялась произвольная дата (в определенном диапазоне) и время у обновленных постов.

Comment: И еще, сможете что-нибудь дельного подсказать по этому вопросу? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1558196/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8

Comment: Как много постов на тестовом сайте и как много постов Вы планируете обновить по итогу? Даты в [диапазоне](https://gist.github.com/samcrosoft/6550473). По второму вопросу, там код нужно писать)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обновить старые посты WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1559453/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-wordpress)